# How can I rotate old systemd journals to a different filesystem?

Tags: systemd, logs, disk-usage, systemd-journald

I want to limit the size of systemd journals (in `/var/log/journal`) by moving old journals to a different filesystem. I know of the setting `SystemMaxUse` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` which makes it possible to specify a size limit for the journal. But instead of removing the old journal entries, I would like to archive them in a different filesystem?

Is there a way to do this? Either a setting for this in systemd, or a way to tell which old files in `/var/log/journal` can safely be moved by a cron job to a different file system.

Comment: You might be able to move an old logfile and replace it by a symbolic link. You will need to test if journalctl is happy with that.

Comment: @meuh: thanks, but I'd rather do this with logfiles that are "finished", and be sure I can move them away without systemd complaining

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to simply move away the "archived" systemd journal files, i.e., the ones that systemd has closed. These are the files in `/var/log/journal/*` with an `@` in their name, as per `man systemd-journald`: "When systemd-journald ceases writing to a journal file, it will be renamed to "original-name@suffix.journal" (or "original-name@suffix.journal~"). Such files are "archived" and will not be written to any more")

Before this, you can optionally rotate the files to make sure the current files are archived, if you want to be sure to move all the log entries. This would be simply `sudo journalctl --rotate`. Then you can do the following to archive the old logs: `sudo mv /var/log/journal/*/*@* /mnt/wherever`.

Another option, if you only want to save the logs the files older than some date, is to use `journalctl --until` to display the logs until some date (and save them somewhere), then `journalctl --vacuum-time` to remove the logs for a corresponding time period.